# How to use this File PHPunit test "extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase"

Tags: php, phpunit

This is FIle Test it require PHPunit and i installed PHPunit , but dont know  use it:

```
 <?php 
    # -*- compile-command: (concat "phpunit " buffer-file-name) -*-
    require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework.php';
    require_once 'common.php';

    class Authentication extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase{
    ........
    }
    ?>
```

it guide :

> When installed ( PHPunit) just run the
>   command phpunit on the top of the
>   directory and it will launch the
>   tests.

But i dont understand how do ><

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of questions you've left unanswered here.  *BUT* right off the bat, I see that you've got a problem with the name of the Authentication class.

PHPUnit requires that any testcases that are run be named according to a specific naming convention.

I can't recall off the top of my head, but I think it's testAuthentication

I'll look into some of my code and get back to you.

EDIT1:
try naming the class `AuthenticationTest` and put a function inside it called `testAuthentication`

that should meet with PHPUnit's requirements to run your tests

Comment: i can't add or naming anything about class this, because it is rackspacecloud's api ( i dont know use, too )

Comment: I think you need a lot more information.  PHPUnit is not trivial to set up correctly.   Is your PHPUnit installed correctly?  For example can you run it against other tests (try the example tests directory).  If this is something about a framework/API that someone else has written for you - have you looked through their documentation?  Usually the command line for PHPUnit is `phpunit filename.php` (unless you have configuration xml etc...)  there's really too much that could be wrong.